# Как можно проверить или создать папку во время создания файла

Tags: c++, файлы, файловая-система

Я могу создать файл через `fstream`, но если я пытаюсь создать файл и укажу путь к несуществующей папке, мне выдаёт ошибку. Изначально я думал, что `fstream` создаст папку, если нет ни файла ни папки.

Вопроса два:

1. Как мне проверить при создании файла, существует ли папка?
2. Как мне создать папку, если ее нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C++ 17 появилась библиотека для работы с директориями (до этого либо boost, либо самому код, который зависит от операционной системы).

```
#include <filesystem>

...

auto result = std::filesystem::create_directory("test");
```

сейчас же вот так можно проверить. если в `result` будет `true`, то значит папка создалась. Если `false`, то она уже была и не удалось её создать.

Comment: Это получается уже создать папку test, а как проверить создана она или нет через функцию if или тут уже не важно будет. И этот код выполняет сразу то и то. А то вдруг он создаст в папке test еще одну папку test

Comment: а в этом случае он её создаст, если её нет. А если она есть, то ничего создано не будет. Ты можешь это проверить сравнив то, что вернула функция. По поводу папки "test" внутри папки "test", нужно это явно указать "test/test".

Comment: Понял, ваш вариант кажется самым простым сейчас :)

Comment: Можно еще перечислить создания сразу нескольких папок а не только одной?

Comment: И как вы отличите `false` от того, что папка уже есть, от случая, если папки нет, но есть **файл** с тем же именем? Или что указан принципиально несоздаваемый путь - например, указан диск, которого нет в системе? И все это - `false`? И, кстати, старые функции от операционки не зависели, если поддерживается POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Если не использовать `<filesystem>`, то есть функции POSIX, типа `stat` - с ними просто, например, проверить существование каталога:

```
bool existDir(const char * name)
{
    struct stat s;
    if (stat(name,&s)) return false;
    return S_ISDIR(s.st_mode);
};
```

Создать каталог - функция `mkdir(const char * name)`, только учесть, что создавать нужно по очереди - например, если в `d:\` нет ничего, а нужно создать `d:\d1\d2\d3`, то сначала нужно создать `d:\d1`, потом `d:\d1\d2` и только потом `d:\d1\d2\d3`.

Если использовать [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), то тут убедиться в существовании каталога позволяет функция [`exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) (при этом убедиться, что она нашла не файл, а именно каталог - через `ststus` и `is_directory`).

Ну, а создать каталог - `create_directory` как аналог `mkdir` (создание по кусочку) или [`create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory), которая создаст все нужные промежуточные каталоги сама.

**Update**

Ну вот примерно такая функция -

```
using namespace std::filesystem;

bool makeDir(const char * dir)
{
    error_code ec;
    if (exists(dir))
        return is_directory(status(dir));
    else
        return create_directories(dir,ec);
}
```

Вернет `true`, если каталог есть или создан, `false` - если нет и не получается создать...

Comment: Все немного сложнее чем я думал, вероятно сам не разберусь. Как я понял filesystem более современный вариант.
Можно мне показать if функцию, которая проверяет папку и создает если ее нету.

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: А зачем нужен `using namespace std::filesystem`, `bool makeDir` и `error_code ec;` ?

Comment: Потому что все функции в этом пространстве имен, потому что вы попросили написать функцию, чтобы не возиться с исключениями... Может, вы хоть немного все же поработаете самостоятельно? Тем более что ссылки на описания в ответе даны!

Comment: для исключений я использую try catch
А ссылки уже читаю и пробую, нужно время что бы разобраться.

Comment: Если хотите с исключениями - параметр `ec` не нужен.